# prove inequlity about cardinality power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following inequlity:$$ |P([0,1]) \backslash P((0,1))| > |P(N)| $$
Now I have the intuition that in the left side of the inequlity there is all the subsets of [0,1] that contain the elements 0 or 1 and that is in the same cardinality is P[0,1] witch is greater then the right hand side (as Cantor proved) but I dont know how to write it down.
Thank you

Comment: First use the known fact that $|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|=|(0,1)|$. Then Cantor's theorem takes care of the rest.

Comment: I remember seeing this or something very similar posted within the past week.  Let me try to find it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The map

$$\wp\big((0,1)\big)\to\wp\big([0,1]\big)\setminus\wp\big((0,1)\big):A\mapsto\{0\}\cup A$$

is an injection.

Comment: @Noam: You’re welcome.